# Where is the Unique Device Identifier (UDID) for an Iphone?

Tags: iphone

I want to add device to my developer account. Where can I find the device id?

There is no Itunes anymore. I have my imei and serial but they are both invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now find this information in Finder. From Apple’s [help topic](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev93ef696c6):

1. Connect your device to your Mac.
2. In Finder, select the device under Locations. If a Trust button appears, click it.
3. Under the device name, click the device family name to show the serial number and device ID (UUID).
4. Copy the device ID by Control-clicking the identifier and choosing Copy from the pop-up menu.